# Save pandas dataframes in loop after manipulating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a loop that takes a series of existing data frames and manipulates their formats and values. I need to know how to create new dataframes containing the modified contents at end the loop.

Example is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create datasets
First = {'GDP':[200,175,150,100]}
Second = {'GDP':[550,200,235,50]}

# Create old_dataframes
old_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(First)
old_df_2 = pd.DataFrame(Second)

# Define references and dictionary
old_dfs = [old_df_1, old_df_2]
new_dfs = ['new_df_1','new_df_2']
dictionary = {}

# Begin Loop
for df, name in zip(old_dfs, new_dfs):

    # Multiply all GDP values by 1.5 in both dataframes
    df = df * 1.5    

    # ISSUE HERE - Supposed to Create new data frames 'new_df_1' & 'new_df_2' containing df*1.5 values: Only appends to dictionary. Does not create new_df_1 & new_df_2
    dictionary[name] = df

# Check for the existance of 'new_df_1 & new_df_2' (They will not appear)
%who_ls DataFrame
```

ISSUE: I have marked the issue above. My code does not create 'new_df_1' & 'new_df_2' dataframes. It simply appends them into dictionary. I need to be able to create new_df_1 & new_df_2 **as separate dataframes.**

Comment: Can you give a sample of your input and expected output? That way it's a bit clearer to see what you need in `dfs` when the loop is said and done

Comment: Thanks for staying persistent with my issue. I have just created an example for you to follow along. I hope it is clear. If run correctly, the final command %who_ls DataFrame should return ['df', 'old_df_1', 'old_df_2','new_df_1','new_df_2']

Comment: What is the issue with your posted loop code?

Comment: The issue with my code is that my code does not create 'new_df_1' & 'new_df_2' as dataframes. The line dictionary[name] = df simply appends them altogether inside dictionary. I don't know how to create the dfs in the loop. if you run my code and check for the new dataframes using %who_ls_DataFrame you won't find 'new_df_1 & new_df_2

Comment: What is wrong with using a dictionary of data frames? Actually, this is the preferred way instead of flooding your global environment with *many* data frames, you use **one** indexed container of data frames. You lose no functionality if data frame is stored in dict, list, tuple, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from copy import deepcopy   #  to copy old dataframes appropriately

# create 2 lists, first holds old dataframes and second holds modified ones
old_dfs_list, new_dfs_list = [pd.DataFrame(First), pd.DataFrame(Second)], []

# process old dfs one by one by iterating over old_dfs_list, 
# copy, modify each and append it to list of new_dfs_list with same index as 
# old df ... so old_dfs_list[1] is mapped to new_dfs_list[1]

for i in range(len(old_dfs_list)):
  # a deep copy prevent changing old dfs by reference
  df_deep_copy = deepcopy(old_dfs_list[i]) 
  df_deep_copy['GDP'] *= 1.5
  new_dfs_list.append(df_deep_copy)

print(old_dfs_list[0])   # to check that old dfs are not changed
print(new_dfs_list[0])
```

[image: results_before_after]

You can also try dictionaries instead of lists to use the names you prefer:

```
import pandas as pd
datadicts_dict = { 
                    'first' :{'GDP':[200,175,150,100]}, 
                    'second':{'GDP':[550,200,235,50]}, 
                    'third' :{'GDP':[600,400,520,100, 800]}
                    }

# Create datasets and store it in a python dictionary
old_dfs_dict, new_dfs_dict = {}, {}    # initialize 2 dicts to hold original and modified dataframes

# process datasets one by one by iterating over datadicts_dict, 
# convert to df save it in old_dfs_dict with same name as the key
# copy, modify each and put it in new_dfs_dict with same key 
# so dataset of key 'first' in datadicts_dict is saved as old_dfs_dict['first'] 
# modified and mapped to new_dfs_dict['first']

for dataset_name, data_dict in datadicts_dict.items():
    old_dfs_dict[dataset_name] = pd.DataFrame({'GDP':data_dict['GDP']})
    new_dfs_dict[dataset_name] = pd.DataFrame({'GDP':data_dict['GDP']}) * 1.5

print(old_dfs_dict['third'])   # to check that old dfs are not changed
print(new_dfs_dict['third'])
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is appending the dataframes together. I need to create separate dataframes 'new_df_1 & 'new_df_2'. Can you please tell me how to adjust/rewrite my command [dictionary[name] = df]. I am only using this approach to reference the names of the dataframes. I don't actually want to store the data in dictionary.

Comment: you have new_dfs_list[0], new_dfs_list[1]    and more if you want.
dataframes are not appended together, they are saved in a list of dataframes: new_dfs_list.
  for exampe If you initialized old_dfs_list with 4 dataframes : old_dfs_list[0] , old_dfs_list[1], old_dfs_list[2], old_dfs_list[3]  ... your new_dfs_list will conatin also new 4 modified dataframes.
  Imagine you have 100 old dataframes ... It is inefficient to create 100 variables with the names new_df_1, new_df_2, ....... , new_df_100  instead create a list new_dframes and index it as:    new_dframes[0],...,new_dframes[99]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up stumbling upon a solution that would work, by thinking about the answer above. The issue I was facing was - extracting appended data from inside the dictionary. It didn't really occur to me that I could extract the data from the dictionary OUTSIDE of the loop and then form the data frame.

```
.
.
.
 # Begin Loop
    for df, name in zip(old_dfs, new_dfs):
    # Multiply all GDP values by 1.5 in both dataframes
    df = df * 1.5    

    # ISSUE HERE - Supposed to Create new data frames 'new_df_1' & 'new_df_2' containing df*1.5 values: Only appends to dictionary. Does not create new_df_1 & new_df_2
    dictionary[name] = df

# Solution - Extract from Dictionary and form Dataframe
new_df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary['new_df_1'])
new_df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary['new_df_2'])

# Check for the existance of 'new_df_1 & new_df_2'
%who_ls DataFrame
```

Comment: You do not need `from_dict` but can simple assign: `new_df_1 = dictionary['new_df_1']`. But as commented above, a dictionary of data frames is preferred way to store many similar structured data frames where you lose no functionality: `dictionary['new_df_1'].head()`, `dictionary['new_df_1'].tail()`, `dictionary['new_df_1'].describe()` ...